# Get man pages for driver functions

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, manpage

I am new to linux device drivers. I would like to know if there are man pages for the driver functions like register_chrdev. If yes, then how do I get them? Is there a package that I can download using apt-get?

Comment: Often it is easier just to run a web search for them.  However, you can also get the kernel tree and run `make mandocs`.

Answer (score 3):

The Linux kernel pages in the `man` program reside in section 9, which is (un)fortunately a non-standard section. See [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/man.1.html). Popular Linux distributions like Ubuntu don't distribute the man pages that fall under this section through their software channels (?).

They're still available, for example, Debian provides [one](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/linux-manual-3.2). There are also online versions of the man pages.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the kernel has an ABI and not an API, as the internal interface is changing quickly.

The best way to learn the Linux kernel is reading the source code. If you are interested in character device drivers, then I would recommend to read LDD3 book and have a look how other device driver use the mentioned calls in your kernel source code. This way you will get an idea how to use the kernel ABI for your driver.