# How to install section 9 of man command in debian

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, manpage

As a newbie of Linux Driver Developer, I often need to find a kernel API's usage.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729387/get-man-pages-for-driver-functions) post's answer, amrith92 said there exit section 9 of man command. After testing on my Debian, however, It seems no section 9 on in my system.

How could I install section 9 of man command in Debian System.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Debian 7.8 (Wheezy) you need to install **linux-manual-3.2** package:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-manual-3.2
```

Package description:

> This package provides the Kernel Hacker's Guide in the form of manual
>    pages, describing the kernel API functions.  They are installed into
>    section 9 of the manual.

In other Debian version try to search package you need:

```
apt-cache search linux-manual
apt-cache show <package_name>
```

Comment: This package doesn't seem to be available in buster.  All I can find is `kernel-doc` (which is a set of HTML documents, not man pages).  Any updated alternative?

Comment: An alternative might be the package `linux-manual-3.16` which can be downloaded from the [Debian FTP server](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux-manual-3.16_3.16.56-1+deb8u1_all.deb).